# Edit row in listView, ArrayAdapter - Android

Tags: android, listview, row, android-arrayadapter

How can I change color of text in single row?

Here is the code where I set adapter and call listView:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), R.layout.row, rez);
 getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own adapter and specify the text color at the position your want:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        if (position == positionYouWantToColor) {
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.mycolor));
        } else {
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.black));
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get error that String[] can not be converted to List<String>.

Comment: I picked up one constructor because it was not specify in your question what was the variable "rez". But you can change the constructor. See edit

Answer (score 0):

In your inside your layout folder you have a layout called row.xml. There you will have a TextView, all you have to do is add:

```
     android:color="@color/your-color"
```

to that xml element.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but not all of row should be same color. I need to you 3 different colors.

Comment: oh you will need to create a custom adapter then